# Accessing a service from a different module in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have  this code where I have a `hexafy` service in one module that  I want to access in a different module:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<p>The hexadecimal value of 255 is:</p>

<h1>{{hex}}</h1>

</div>

<div ng-app="myApp2" ng-controller="myCtrl2">

<p>The hexadecimal value of 155 is:</p>

<h1>{{hex2}}</h1>

</div>

<p>A custom service whith a method that converts a given number into a hexadecimal number.</p>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.service('hexafy', function() {
    this.myFunc = function (x) {
        return x.toString(16);
    }
});
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, hexafy) {
  $scope.hex = hexafy.myFunc(255);
});

var app2 = angular.module('myApp2', ['myApp']);
app2.controller('myCtrl2', function($scope, hexafy) {
  $scope.hex = hexafy.myFunc(155);
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

However, the `hex2` model in this example never gets resolved! What am I doing wrong?

I found my solution! As per the comments below, you can really only have 1 angular app per page but as many controllers as you want.

This is the working solution!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="myCtrl">

<p>The hexadecimal value of 255 is:</p>

<h1>{{hex}}</h1>

</div>

<div ng-controller="myCtrl2">

<p>The hexadecimal value of 155 is:</p>

<h1>{{hex2}}</h1>

</div>

<p>A custom service whith a method that converts a given number into a hexadecimal number.</p>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.service('hexafy', function() {
    this.myFunc = function (x) {
        return x.toString(16);
    }
});
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, hexafy) {
  $scope.hex = hexafy.myFunc(255);
});

app.controller('myCtrl2', function($scope, hexafy) {
  $scope.hex2 = hexafy.myFunc(155);
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think it's because you're declaring 2 ng-apps. `myApp` is already included in `myApp2` so just move ` ng-app="myApp2"` to body

Comment: @austinthedeveloper you're exactly right on the 2 ng-apps, I got the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document. The first ngApp found in the document will be used to define the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. To run multiple applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them using angular.bootstrap instead.

So define the myApp2 div with an id .

```
<div id="App2" ng-app="myApp2" ng-controller="myCtrl2">
```

So u have to manually bootstrap the app2 as below

```
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("App2"), ['myApp2']);
```

One more mistake in ur code . The hex2 model should be set as

```
$scope.hex2 = hexafy.myFunc(155); // it was $scope.hex before
```